# Enable setfattr (extended attributes) in OpenSUSE-13.X

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, opensuse, file-attributes

I have a requirement where i need to add some extended attributes on a symlink and a file.However "setfattr:operation not supported" error is not allowing me to do that in OpenSUSE.

```
$setfattr -n "user.name" -v "myname" LICENCE.txt 
setfattr: LICENCE.txt: Operation not supported

$attr -s name -V myname LICENCE.txt 
attr_set: Operation not permitted
Could not set "name" for LICENCE.txt

$cat /etc/SuSE-release 
openSUSE 13.2 (x86_64)

$vi /etc/fstab
UUID=796465a8-614a-4977-8d67-269f4239e9e8 /home xfs defaults 1 2

$zcat /proc/config.gz | grep XATTR
CONFIG_REISERFS_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_TMPFS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_SQUASHFS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_F2FS_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_CIFS_XATTR=y
```

Is this because of the absence of CONFIG_XFS_XATTR=y in my config? 
Is there any way I can enable XATTR in my environment?

Comment: In your terminal listing, could you also include the command and error verbatim?

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're the owner?  The CONFIG_XFS_XATTR idea is worth a test, but given that your file system is xfs, it seems like that would have been enabled already.

Comment: Yes I am owner.If it is enabled then iwonder why is it not listed in config and is not working

Comment: Have you gone back over your menuconfig for configuring your kernel?

Comment: No i have not and i am not familiar with how to go about that.

Comment: This looks useful: (the "make menuconfi"g step is what I was refering to):  https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/compiling-de-linux-kernel-suse-way/